# Printing multiple elements from a list

Tags: r

```
numbers = 1:100

for(x in seq(26,1,-2)) {
  print(numbers[x:x+2]) 
}
```

And the above prints:

```
[1] 28
[1] 26
    {etc}
[1] 4
```

My question is why doesn't the loop print something like a section (`26 27 28`) of the list? Why does it only print out one number per iteration? And what would I have to change for the output to be slices of the list? Desired out put

```
[1] 27 28
[1] 25 26
   {etc}
[1] 3 4
```

This is confusing to me since

```
numbers[1:5]
# prints [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Use `numbers[x:(x+2)]`. Check out the `?Syntax` help page for the order of operations of different operators.

Answer (score 2):

You need some parentheses, otherwise it is `(x:x)+2`

```
for(x in seq(26,1,-2)) {
  print(numbers[x:(x+2)]) 
}
```